# getting 404 page not found error when redirecting in admin

Tags: magento

I had installed a custom extension on both live and local server. It is running fine on local server but gives issues i.e. redirects to frontend and gives 404 page not found error when I click on custom extension page in admin.

Below is my config.xml and extension.xml file code:

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Submitdigital_CustomLogo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </Submitdigital_CustomLogo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customlogo>
                <class>Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Helper</class>
            </customlogo>
        </helpers>
       <blocks>
            <customlogo>
                <class>Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Block</class>
            </customlogo>
        </blocks>
         <models>
            <customlogo>
                <class>Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customlogo_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </customlogo>
            <customlogo_mysql4>
                <class>Submitdigital_CustomLogo_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <customlogo>
                        <table>customlogo</table>
                    </customlogo>
                </entities>
            </customlogo_mysql4>
        </models>
                <resources>
            <customlogo_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Submitdigital_CustomLogo</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customlogo_setup>
            <customlogo_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customlogo_write>
            <customlogo_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customlogo_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <admin_customlogo>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Submitdigital_CustomLogo</module>
                    <frontName>admin_customlogo</frontName>
                </args>
            </admin_customlogo>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <customlogo>
                <title>SubmitDigital</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <customlogo>
                        <title>Manage Customlogo</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>customlogo/adminhtml_customlogo</action>
                    </customlogo>
                </children>
            </customlogo>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <customlogo translate="title">
                            <title>SubmitDigital</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <customlogo translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Customlogo</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </customlogo>
                            </children>
                        </customlogo>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customlogo>
                    <file>customlogo.xml</file>
                </customlogo>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
   <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customlogo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Submitdigital_CustomLogo</module>
                    <frontName>customlogo</frontName>
                </args>
            </customlogo>
        </routers>
         <layout>
            <updates>
                <customlogo>
                    <file>customlogo.xml</file>
                </customlogo>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

extension.xml(customlogo.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <customlogo_adminhtml_customlogo_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="customlogo/adminhtml_customlogo" name="customlogo" />
    </reference>
  </customlogo_adminhtml_customlogo_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Logged out and in again in the backend?

Comment: Thanks Roy for reply. I tried this but it did not worked. Is there any other way out to this problem?